# If a natural transform is an equivalence, under which circumstances is the induced derived natural transform also an equivalence?

Tags: derived-categories, derived-functors

More specifically, let A and B be two abelian categories. Suppose $F:A\to B$ is a left exact functor, $G:A\to A$ and $H:B\to B$ are two right exact functors such that $F\circ G=H\circ F$.

With which kind of extra assumptions can we show that $RF\circ LG=LH\circ RF$?